# Effective Testing of a Spring Boot Application Method Involving Entity Mocking

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking

I'm currently working on testing a method within my Spring Boot application, and I could use some guidance as my previous attempts haven't aligned with the platform's guidelines. The method I'm trying to test involves setting the status of a TransferEntity. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in figuring out the appropriate testing approach for this scenario.

Here's the method I'm looking to test:

```
public static void setStatus(TransferEntity entity, String status) {
    // Implementation details here
}
```

My main dilemma lies in how to effectively test this method. I'm unsure whether I should be mocking the TransferEntity data or if there's a better approach. If someone could provide me with insights or steps on how to go about testing this method properly, I would be extremely grateful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: pls post the whole method

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends the first things coming to minds.

- Which library are you for unit testing? What is the content of your
  method?
- Are you calling another method from you method?
- Do you want to perform integration test over your entity?

  If yes, you would configure database for test scope.
- Why you are using static method to set your entity?

In conclusion, please share more detail by sharing code block etc

Answer (score 0):

are you performing unit testing on this method by directly calling it?
if yes then you can mock TransferEntity and use when(...).thenReturn(...) kind of snippet. but your question is very generic so difficult to answer concretely.